# How to Find a control created in DocumentViewer toolbar?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a `TextBox` control in `DocumentViewer`'s Toolbar for displaying the current page no. and giving the user a GoTo type facility.

following is the code:

```
<Style x:Key="DocumentViewerStyle1" BasedOn="{x:Null}" TargetType="{x:Type DocumentViewer}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=PUIDocumentViewerContextMenu, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type System_Windows_Documents:PresentationUIStyleResources}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DocumentViewer}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Focusable="False">
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <ContentControl Grid.Column="0" Focusable="{TemplateBinding Focusable}" Grid.Row="0" Style="{DynamicResource ContentControlStyle1}" TabIndex="0"/>
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" CanContentScroll="true" Grid.Column="0" Focusable="{TemplateBinding Focusable}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" IsTabStop="true" Grid.Row="1" TabIndex="1"/>
                            <DockPanel Grid.Row="1">
                                <FrameworkElement DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}"/>
                                <Rectangle Height="10" Visibility="Visible" VerticalAlignment="top">
                                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                                            <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                                <GradientStopCollection>
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#66000000" Offset="0"/>
                                                    <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="1"/>
                                                </GradientStopCollection>
                                            </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                     </Rectangle.Fill>
                                </Rectangle>

                                <!--<Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Width="100"/>-->
                            </DockPanel>
                            <!--<TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="txtBlock" Text="Hello World"/>-->
                            <ContentControl x:Name="PART_FindToolBarHost" Grid.Column="0" Focusable="{TemplateBinding Focusable}" Grid.Row="2" TabIndex="2"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Aspire Education" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Margin="300,0,0,0" Foreground="#FF0758DC" FontSize="18" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="ContentControlStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                    <ToolBar Focusable="{TemplateBinding Focusable}" ToolBarTray.IsLocked="True" Language="en-us" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Continue" Uid="ToolBar_2">
                        <Button x:Name="PrintButton" Background="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=PUIDocumentViewerPrintButton, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type System_Windows_Documents:PresentationUIStyleResources}}}" CommandTarget="{Binding TemplatedParent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Command="ApplicationCommands.Print" IsTabStop="True" Margin="2" Padding="2" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=PUIDocumentViewerButtonStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type System_Windows_Documents:PresentationUIStyleResources}}}" ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True" TabIndex="0" ToolTip="Print (Ctrl+P)" Uid="Button_14" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="24"/>
                        <Button x:Name="CopyButton" Background="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=PUIDocumentViewerCopyButton, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type System_Windows_Documents:PresentationUIStyleResources}}}" CommandTarget="{Binding TemplatedParent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy" IsTabStop="True" Margin="2" Padding="2" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=PUIDocumentViewerButtonStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type System_Windows_Documents:PresentationUIStyleResources}}}" ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True" TabIndex="1" ToolTip="Copy (Ctrl+C)" Uid="Button_15" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="24"/>
                        <Separator Uid="Separator_110"/>
                        <Button x:Name="ZoomInButton" Background="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=PUIDocumentViewerZoomInButton, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type System_Windows_Documents:PresentationUIStyleResources}}}" CommandTarget="{Binding TemplatedParent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Command="NavigationCommands.IncreaseZoom" IsTabStop="True" Margin="2" Padding="2" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=PUIDocumentViewerButtonStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type System_Windows_Documents:PresentationUIStyleResources}}}" ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True" TabIndex="3" ToolTip="Increase the size of the content (Ctrl +)" Uid="Button_16" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="24"/>
                        <Button x:Name="ZoomOutButton" Background="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=PUIDocumentViewerZoomOutButton, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type System_Windows_Documents:PresentationUIStyleResources}}}" CommandTarget="{Binding TemplatedParent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Command="NavigationCommands.DecreaseZoom" IsTabStop="True" Margin="2" Padding="2" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=PUIDocumentViewerButtonStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type System_Windows_Documents:PresentationUIStyleResources}}}" ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True" TabIndex="4" ToolTip="Decrease the size of the content (Ctrl -)" Uid="Button_17" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="24"/>
                        <Separator Uid="Separator_111"/>
                        <Button x:Name="ActualSizeButton" Background="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=PUIDocumentViewerActualSizeButton, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type System_Windows_Documents:PresentationUIStyleResources}}}" CommandTarget="{Binding TemplatedParent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" CommandParameter="100.0" Command="NavigationCommands.Zoom" IsTabStop="True" Margin="2" Padding="2" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle1}" ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True" TabIndex="5" ToolTip="100% (Ctrl+1)" Uid="Button_18" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="24"/>
                        <Button x:Name="PageWidthButton" Background="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=PUIDocumentViewerPageWidthButton, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type System_Windows_Documents:PresentationUIStyleResources}}}" CommandTarget="{Binding TemplatedParent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Command="DocumentViewer.FitToWidthCommand" IsTabStop="True" Margin="2" Padding="2" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=PUIDocumentViewerButtonStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type System_Windows_Documents:PresentationUIStyleResources}}}" ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True" TabIndex="6" ToolTip="Page Width (Ctrl+2)" Uid="Button_19" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="24"/>
                        <Button x:Name="WholePageButton" Background="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=PUIDocumentViewerWholePageButton, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type System_Windows_Documents:PresentationUIStyleResources}}}" CommandTarget="{Binding TemplatedParent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" CommandParameter="1" Command="DocumentViewer.FitToMaxPagesAcrossCommand" IsTabStop="True" Margin="2" Padding="2" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=PUIDocumentViewerButtonStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type System_Windows_Documents:PresentationUIStyleResources}}}" ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True" TabIndex="7" ToolTip="Whole Page (Ctrl+3)" Uid="Button_20" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="24"/>
                        <Button x:Name="TwoPagesButton" Background="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=PUIDocumentViewerTwoPagesButton, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type System_Windows_Documents:PresentationUIStyleResources}}}" CommandTarget="{Binding TemplatedParent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" CommandParameter="2" Command="DocumentViewer.FitToMaxPagesAcrossCommand" IsTabStop="True" Margin="2" Padding="2" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=PUIDocumentViewerButtonStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type System_Windows_Documents:PresentationUIStyleResources}}}" ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True" TabIndex="8" ToolTip="Two Pages (Ctrl+4)" Uid="Button_21" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="24"/>
                        <Separator Uid="Separator_112"/>
                        <TextBox x:Name="txtCurrentPage" Text="580" Width="30" BorderBrush="Black" TextChanged="txtCurrentPage_TextChanged"></TextBox>
                        <TextBox x:Name="txtTotalPage" Text="/250" Width="40" IsReadOnly="True" BorderBrush="Black" Foreground="Black"></TextBox>
                    </ToolBar>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

But when i am trying to access that textbox, it's showing null.

here is my code behind.

```
    private void txtCurrentPage_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainWindow mn = new MainWindow();
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)mn.FindName("txtCurrentPage");

        if (tb != null)
        {
            DocumentViewerReading.GoToPage(Convert.ToInt32(tb.Text));
        }
    }
```

Please Help

Comment: Where is it showing Null? Or is it throwing a Null pointer Exception?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

following is the complete solution :-

```
<Style x:Key="DocumentViewerStyle1" BasedOn="{x:Null}" TargetType="{x:Type DocumentViewer}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=PUIDocumentViewerContextMenu, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type System_Windows_Documents:PresentationUIStyleResources}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DocumentViewer}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Focusable="False">
                        <Grid x:Name="grdDocumentViewer" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <ContentControl Grid.Column="0" Focusable="{TemplateBinding Focusable}" Grid.Row="0" Style="{DynamicResource ContentControlStyle1}" TabIndex="0"/>
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" CanContentScroll="true" Grid.Column="0" Focusable="{TemplateBinding Focusable}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" IsTabStop="true" Grid.Row="1" TabIndex="1"/>
                            <DockPanel Grid.Row="1">
                                <FrameworkElement DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}"/>
                                <Rectangle Height="10" Visibility="Visible" VerticalAlignment="top">
                                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                                            <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                                <GradientStopCollection>
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#66000000" Offset="0"/>
                                                    <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="1"/>
                                                </GradientStopCollection>
                                            </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                                </Rectangle>

                                <!--<Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Width="100"/>-->
                            </DockPanel>
                            <!--<TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="txtBlock" Text="Hello World"/>-->
                            <ContentControl x:Name="PART_FindToolBarHost" Grid.Column="0" Focusable="{TemplateBinding Focusable}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,20,0" Grid.Row="0" TabIndex="2"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="tbTopicName" Text="" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,2,0,0" Foreground="#FF0758DC" FontSize="20" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

//**And following is the Code Behind**

```
Grid gMain = (Grid)DocumentViewerReading.Template.FindName("grdDocumentViewer", DocumentViewerReading);
        TextBlock tb = (TextBlock)gMain.FindName("tbTopicName");
        tb.Text = header;
```

That's it.
And Thanks Andy.

Comment: You are welcome but I don't think the answer you've given yourself actually answers the question you posted, consider writing your answer as an actual answer for others that come looking.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to find the control again, it's reference should be in the sender parameter.

```
private void txtCurrentPage_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;

        if (tb != null)
        {
            DocumentViewerReading.GoToPage(Convert.ToInt32(tb.Text));
        }
    }
```

You were creating a new instance of a window every time the contents of the text box changes and attempting to look for a textbox within that new window, that's not quite how it should work, you've already got an instance of the window since the users are typing on it.

Comment: And what if i need to find that textbox? How can i do that

Comment: If you really want to use find to get a reference to the textbox you you can probably use this.FindName("txtCurrentPage"); which will give you a reference to the textbox. you have correctly used the x:Name property which FindName will use.